# Decorating parse tree using attribute grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, parse-tree

Given the following attribute grammar for type declarations, I need to be able to produce a parse tree for any given string, for example "A, B : C;", and then decorate the tree.

I can generally do this for simple attribute grammars and when its obvious what the attributes are, but I can not decipher what `out_tab` and `in_tab` are. Yes, this is my homework and I am not asking for the solution, I am asking for guidance on what these attributes mean and possible examples to assist me.

```
decl -> ID decl_tail
    decl.t := decl_tail.t
    decl_tail.in_tab := insert(decl,in_tab, ID.n, decl_tail.t)
    decl.out_tab := decl_tail.out_tab
decl_tail -> , decl
    decl_tail.t := decl.t
    decl.in_tab := decl_tail.in_tab
    decl_tail.out_tab := decl.out_tab
decl_tail -> : ID ;
    decl_tail.t := ID.n
    decl_tail.out_tab := decl_tail.in_tab
```

Answer (score 3):

Several years after, I hope you finished well your home work :)

about your exercise:

`decl.t` and `decl_tail.t` are synthetized atributes that copy the Type name (`ID.n`) and pass it for each parent production in the parsing tree

when a production `decl -> ID decl_tail` is reached, the `in_tab` attributte keeps a kind of list of  relationship between identifiers and types (it is not clear the type of `in_tab` but we can assume a list of tuples `(identifier; type)`). This attribute is inherited, so the list will start to be constructed in the top most production (leftmost identifier), and continue constructing it from left to right and finish it in the rightmost identifier.

Then the list is finished to be constructed when `decl_tail -> : ID;` is reached so a synthesised attribute (`out_tab`) is used to synthesise the result again to the starting symbol.

this drawing was the best I could do for drawing the decorated tree and graph dependence:

[image]

Blue arrows are the synthetizing of the `t` attribute, the green arrows are how the `in` list is constructed and the red arrows are how the result is synthesized to the initial symbol

Comment: In theory you'd pass the tab attribute as a value.  In practice, tab is what amounts to a symbol table and can be pretty big.    So you might instead consider passing tab in practice as a *reference* to the symbol table.   This makes more sense when you consider that the symbol table itself is likely to be composed of sub-symbol tables, and what you want tab to do is reference the innermost scope, assuming each scope can find its parent scope.

Comment: you are right ... but we are in the "theory scope".

the initial post talked about an "Attribute Grammar" that is a purely theorical tool. As a restriction, AG can only have assignements between attributes and can only call functions with no side effects. Writing in a global symbol table is a side effect, so it is out of scope of an AG

Comment: It might be out of scope if you insist that it isn't an AG if it isn't functional.  We build perfectly fine AG systems that don't have this functional property and are damn useful for building symbol tables exactly as I have described including for C++17. (See my bio).  Software Engineering isn't about purist theory; its about what works in practice.